# Measuring moisture in walls remotely

Tags: measurements

There exist devices (e.g. Bosch PTD 1) which measure the temperature and humidity/moisture of the room and remotely (without contact) of a wall they are pointed at.

I understand that you can measure temperature remotely using basically an infrared camera and Stefan–Boltzmann law (and making assumptions about the emissivity). I also understand that you can measure moisture in a wall by placing electrodes on it and measuring the conductance or dielectric constant.

I was wondering how moisture is measured by these devices *remotely* when they are typically about one metre from the wall? The device in question includes a laser, but this might just be an aid to show the area being measured.